# angularjs fill scope variable with REST service in existing controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, this is a continuation for [externalizing ng-class for table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801380/externalizing-ng-class-for-table-cells)

the jsFiddle chosen there is http://jsfiddle.net/mTJDh/5/

the code

```
$scope.users = [{
    name: 'PEDC',
    days: [{
        number: '1',
        func: 'guard'
    }, {
        number: '2',
        func: 'guard'
    }, {
        number: '3',
        func: 'guard'
    }, {
        number: '4',
        func: ['guard', 'spoc', 'holiday']
    }]
}, {
    name: 'JOVH',
    days: [{
        number: '1',
        func: 'guard'
    }, {
        number: '2',
        func: 'guard'
    }, {
        number: '3',
        func: 'spoc'
    }, {
        number: '4',
        func: 'guard'
    }]
}];
```

which is in a controller, should be filled by a REST-call.

when I use

```
function getUsersDays($scope, $http) {
$http.get('https://middleware.infraserv.be/middleware/zorglubV2_angular_dev/rest.php?userDayList').success(function(data) {
    $scope.userDays = data;
});
```

I get it to work to fill my table, but then I can't style my table anymore as done in the other question. (Here it says userDays instead of users because I used other variables while testing)

How can I combine the 2 functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/4AEFZZSBuJg0hUeoW9Tv?p=preview

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {

    $scope.users = data; // not $scope.userDays 
});
```

Comment: even though there is an issue in the plunker(not sure what, maybe just my internet-settings) this has resolved my issue purely on the code.